# Google Drive consent page message

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I've recently integrated Google Drive API with our app and set the scope for only files that our app creates `drive.file`

[image: GCP Settings]

According to their docs this scope would have access only to files it creates.

[image: Google Drive Scopes]

For some reason when the users are going through the consent page they see a message saying that they're allowing us to access ALL their files on Google Drive.

[image: Consent Screen]

Since this message is misleading our users can lose trust in our app from the get-go.

Does anybody have any experience with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your code.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no code. The settings are managed through GCP console. I've updated the question with screenshots to elaborate on the issue.

Comment: The code of your app. You must be using some methods that need the `drive` scope. I cannot tell you which part of your code requests this scope without seeing the source code.

Comment: @ziganotschka yes the issue was in the code after all. The scope for the packages used was requesting ```drive``` as the scope. I changed it to ```drive.file``` and the consent screen message changed.